# Election Up/Down vote stats

Tags: discussion, election, election-page

I was taking a look at the [GIS SE Election Stats page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#gis.stackexchange) and noticed that the Up/Down vote stats don't match up with the profile Up/Down vote numbers.

Stats Page shows 223 down votes:
[image]

But profile only shows 69 down votes:
[image]

Have I missed something somewhere regarding how these stats are calculated?  The up votes don't match either, but they're much closer (1270 v 1254).

Comment: No repro. Assuming [this is the user you refer to](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64785/midavalo?tab=topactivity), I see 223 all time downvotes in their profile. Where you see that "69 Votes Cast" exactly?? Oh wait, it's you..

Comment: Yes that's right, it is me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at your *votes activity* but that excludes the votes you casted on now deleted questions.

This is mine on MSE:

[image: my votes]

If you go to the bottom of your [profile summary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64785/midavalo?tab=summary) you see the actual number of down votes you have ever cast, including those on now-deleted posts.

This is my total on MSE:

[image]

Comment: Was going to post such answer. Nice! :-)

Comment: Ok thank you, that makes sense