# Images are not centered horizontally

Tags: bug, android-app

When looking to [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284688/election-up-down-vote-stats) in Android app all images aligned to left:

> [image: Android left]

For iOS-app and mobile version of web all images centered horizontally:

> [image: iOS]
>
> [image: mobile]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)

Comment: On the site images are also aligned to the left, so isn't it a bug then in the iOS app that the images are centered?

Comment: @rene Android and iOS are *mobile* OSs, so I think messages should be formatted same as on mobile version of web site. Is not it?

Comment: Yeah, that is also a valid reasoning ;), if anything let's go for consistency, what ever consistency that is.

Comment: Personally I think it looks kind of dumb to center images like that. Not sure why that was ever done. I hope it gets undone.