# Images in user profile fills width in the iOS app

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, ios-app, images

Images in posts and user profile seem to fill screen's width when displaying in the iOS app:

> [image]
>
> *(The gray highlight is not part of the image, this screenshot was taken by click and holding on the image)*

This is what it looks like on the web:

> [image: Image 2]

This snowflake, [image], displays weirdly in the iOS app as seen above.

Comment: It's the same on the mobile site too and afaik by-design (not saying that it's good). There's even a [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284691/307988) that Android *isn't* the same...

Comment: @cai seems the more relevant for this question is an another my [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287979/339911) :)